# Call another function when main() exits

Tags: c, program-entry-point

Is it possible to call an extra function when main() exits in C?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can register functions to run after `main` exits using [the `atexit` function](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/atexit.html).

MSDN has [a nice succinct example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tze57ck3.aspx) of how this is done.  Basically, the functions registered with `atexit` are executed in reverse order of when they were registered.

Comment: atexit() is a frequent source of platform-specific weirdness and unpredictable crashes.  For example the OpenBSD manpage advises not to use it.  I was looking for some articles I read circa 2003 on the subject, but was unable to find them...

Comment: @asveikau: OpenBSD advises not to use it because of races at exit-time. Is it the case that a single-threaded OpenBSD program suffers from weirdness and unpredictable crashes on exit if it has used atexit() naively? If so that's a worry, but I don't see why in principle a non-compliant implementation of the function on one platform should mean you ought not to use it on other platforms. If you write multi-threaded code, then of course you have to look to your platform's treatment of "hidden" global data like the atexit list...

Comment: @Steve I wish I could find those old articles on the subject so I could refresh my memory on their particular reasoning.  I seem to recall it applied to other systems as well.  FWIW, I've experienced a few bugs firsthand because atexit() was called without realizing that the handlers persist on a fork(), or exit() was called from within a signal handler or while a lock is held, or if the handler comes from a shared library that gets unloaded.  Similar to signals, you really should be careful where your handler comes from and what it does.

Comment: I guess you can be careless about how you call exit, or you can be careless about how you call atexit, but not both. Most programmers prefer the former.

Comment: @Steve: Even without `atexit`, being careless about how you call `exit` is dangerous. It's not async-signal-safe, and since it flushes all open files, it's almost sure to give you problems if you break the rules about calling it.

Answer (score 9):

Try the `atexit()` function:

```
void myfunc() {
    /* Called when the program ends */
}

int main( int arc, char *argv[] ) {
    atexit( myfunc );
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Great question and answers. Just a side note. Abuse of a similar feature in Delphi libraries led to applications which are annoyingly slow on close.

Answer (score 1):

While [**`atexit()`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atexit.html) is the standard for registering a function to run at process termination, GCC provides a *destructor* [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)<sup>*****</sup> that causes a function to be called automatically when `main()` has completed or `exit()` has been called.

```
void __attribute__ ((destructor)) my_fini(void);
```

<sup>* **GCC specific**</sup>